# How can I make an array instead of calling date() 3 times?

Tags: php, date

```
$this_year = date('Y');
$days_this_year = 365 + date('L');
$day_number = date('z') + 1;
```

Can I make an array instead of calling date() 3 times? I tried a few times, but could not figure out the syntax I needed

Comment: Why do you need an array? Using a `DateTime` object - or even a timestamp - you have everything that you need and you can generate whatever output you need.

Answer (score 0):

This approach creates a string with the values separated by spaces and explodes it into an array.

```
$values = date('Y L z');
$items = explode(' ',$values);
echo 'Year: '.$items[0].PHP_EOL;
echo 'Days this year: '.($items[1]+365).PHP_EOL;
echo 'Day number: '.$items[2].PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list($this_year,$days_this_year,$day_number) = preg_split("/[\s]/",date('Y L z'));
echo $this_year . PHP_EOL;
echo ($days_this_year + 365) . PHP_EOL;
echo ($day_number  + 1) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most readable, but just for fun, here's a one-liner:

```
$array = array_map('array_sum', array_map('array_merge', [[0], [365], [1]], json_decode(date('[[Y],[L],[z]]'), true)));
```